# ThreadLocal not being property set in overloaded thread constructor

Tags: java, thread-local

I have the following classes

This class is used to keep all my ThreadLocal data members

```
public class ThreadLocalManager
{
    public static final ThreadLocal<String> myThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal<String>();
}
```

The following class is used to test ThreadLocal

```
public class Test extends Common implements Runnable
{
    public Test(String country, String machine)
    {
        Common.machine = machine;
        Common.country = country;
        ThreadLocalManager.myThreadLocal.set("HI");
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                Liker liker = new Liker();
                liker.run();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This class is used to test to see if the datamemeber is set correctly

```
public class Liker
{
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println((String) ThreadLocalManager.myThreadLocal.get());
    }
}
```

EDIT

This is how my Thread is created

```
Thread newThread = new Thread(new Test(country, machine));
newThread.start();
```

One thing I'm confused about is that just as above, when I call `ThreadLocalManager.myThreadLocal.set("HI");` in the `Test` constructor, I get `null` from the `Liker` run method. But if I call `ThreadLocalManager.myThreadLocal.set("HI");` in the `Test` run method, `Liker.run()` prints `HI`

I thought that the value should be accessible from all classes and objects as long as they are from the same thread. Why does not the value `HI` get stored when I call it from the constructor?

Comment: How are you creating and using your `Test` object(s)? Please show us a complete [mcve].

Comment: @JohnKugelman I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost answered on your question here -

> as long as they are from the same thread

Constructor of `Test` method run in different thread, than code which runs inside `Test::run` method.